# Blogger: canonical or localized url?

Tags: url, tags, blogger, canonical-link

I'm struggling to find something relevant on the web.
I'm an `Italian user` with an `Italian Blogger blog`. Since a few years, Blogger introduced `localized domains`, in my case `.it`. When I try to visit `[ADDRESS].blogspot.com`, it automatically redirects to `[ADDRESS].blogspot.it` . The same happens to `foreign visitors`: french people will see `[ADDRESS].blogspot.fr`, `german` people will see `[ADDRESS].blogspot.de` and so on, even if they visit `[ADDRESS].blogspot.com` .

Until now I kept sharing and promoting `.it` version of my `blog`... but now I have some doubts about it.

> Question 1.

Do you think should I switch everything into `.com` (i.e. the canonical url) or keep `.it` ??!

> Question 2.

Within the blog code, there are a lot of `data:blog.url` and `data:post.url` tags that imho I think indicate the `.it` url. Should I replace all of them with `data:blog.canonicalUrl` and `data:post.canonicalUrl` if I want to adopt `.com` url?!

If YES, should I make further changes in the code?

A big thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should use .com instead of .it because it's better for SEO and blog ranking.

If you want to disable country redirect for your blog, you should try code below.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var blog = document.location.hostname;
var slug = document.location.pathname;
var ctld = blog.substr(blog.lastIndexOf("."));
if (ctld != ".com") {
var ncr = "http://" + blog.substr(0, blog.indexOf("."));
ncr += ".blogspot.com/ncr" + slug;
window.location.replace(ncr);
}
</script>
```

the script will redirect your blog to `http://YOURBLOG.blogspot.com/ncr` wich `ncr` mean "**No Country Redirect**".

script also work for worldwide visitor, so your visitor from French also redirected to .com not .fr

For case number 2, I think it will redirected automatic with 301 status. e.g if you share an articel with URL `http://YOURBLOG.blogspot.it/2014/05/post-title.html` will redirected to `http://YOURBLOG.blogspot.com/2014/05/post-title.html`.

And about 301 redirect, don't worry it's good for SEO :)

Some reference:
http://techbymak.com/stop-country-redirection-in-blogger-blog.html
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_301